# Right word choice for sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I have recently learned the word maudlin which means tearfully sentimental. I tried to use the sentence in this way.

> Sam was being humiliated in the class by the professor.He became maudlin and started crying.

I got it checked twice from native speakers of english language and they both said it does not seem like correct word choice. I could not get their further comments.So can anybody tell me the reason?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: "By professor"... ?

Comment: @Micheal Harvey...I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: Did you mean 'by **the** professor', or 'by **a** professor'?

Comment: @Micheal Harvey..did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To English speakers, "maudlin" usually means "feeling sad and sorry for yourself, especially after you have drunk a lot of alcohol", and, alcohol or not, implies that the sadness is self-pitying, excessive or exaggerated. It would not be the best choice for the situation you describe. I suggest "upset" or "unhappy".

[Maudlin (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/maudlin)

Comment: @Micheal Harvey...Is it possible to know that who downvoted the question? As I have edited the question, I don't think this question deserves to be downvoted.

Comment: Nobody can tell who gave a downvote, not even the moderators or operators of this site.